# Intel 7265 Chipset, Elementary can't connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, networking

Ran: `lspci -vvnn | grep Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
```

I'm not sure how to check to make sure my driver is up-to-date or if the firmware is correct. Can someone help point me in the right direction so I can connect to the wifi on Elementary OS?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a laptop? Brand?

With my HP Omen and Intel 7260 (no dual-band) I had to blacklist acer_wmi to connect with Wifi.

Create a .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/ with

> blacklist acer_wmi

Save and Reboot.

Comment: Its an ASUS labtop

Comment: I tried blacklisting acer_wmi but it didn't work. Something interesting.. last night I gave up trying to connect and this morning when I opened my laptop it was connected to wifi. I was doing some updates, rebooted, and suddenly wasn't able to connect anymore.

Comment: Try to blacklist hp_wmi instead of acer_wmi (remove the old file).

Comment: Reboot and 'sudo rfkill unblock all'

Comment: Ran sudo rfkill list first:  <br /> `0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I can't figure out how to insert a newline. Basically I can see that phy0: Wireless LAN is soft blocked and so is asus-wlan: Wireless LAN

Comment: However, when I run `sudo rfkill unblock all` nothing is unblocked.

Comment: Tried unblocking them individually, and though I am able to unblock the soft block, it triggers the phy0 to be hard blocked. Not sure how this works.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. If two questions cover the same topic, please vote to close one as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score -2):

The answer I found to this problem specific to my ASUS laptop can be seen here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

Thanks for the help @Davide

Comment: You might want to outline the solution in your answer, so that it is available for those who do not want to follow the link.

Comment: Make an effort and give all the important details inside your answer. Posting links here is not the way to do things, and the link you posted contains far too many details.